# Restricting content by Role.GetRolesforUser in application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have an MVC 5.2 application that takes advantage of ASP.Identity and the enhanced role services.  All users are assigned a role that is prefixed as such:  Corporate for internal users (e.g. "CorporateAdmin") and Client for external users (e.g. "ClientAdmin").

I have content that I want only to display in the view to external clients only that are authenticated.  I have tried a variety of formats of the following:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && !Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Corporate"))
    {
         *Content to be displayed*
    }
```

The error message returned is "CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

I have also tried:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && Roles.GetRolesForUser().Contains("Corporate") == false)
    {
        *Content to be displayed*
    }
```

and

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("CorporateAdmin") == false)
    {
        *Content to be displayed*
    }
```

all receiving the same error.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The logic is flawed; GetRoles returns a list of roles. You should check each role instead of checking "Corporate" is one of the roles

Comment: Right.  But should not the list, if any among it contain the word "Corporate" trigger the bool to false?

Comment: Yes. That is why I didn't post this as an answer. I suspect the code between the braces. Could you post that or just test without the if.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this errors means that `GetRolesForUser` returns an array of strings, not a list of strings. An array has not `Contains` method.

Try:

```
@if (Context.User.IsInRole("Corporate"))
{
   "Content to be displayed"
}
```

Comment: "Corporate" is not a role.  It is a prefix for a role.  So must I check against all roles prefixed with "Corporate"?  This seems unnecessarily burdensome.

Comment: Try use LINQ: `Roles.GetRolesForUser().Exists(role => role.StartsWith("Corporate"))`. You need `@using System.Linq` in your Razor view. `StartsWith` checks for prefixes. You can call `Contains` that checks prefixes, postfixes, and infixes.